# Cancel a Stripe subscription auto renewal after first Payment -Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have used stripe plugin and gravity form for payment in my WordPress site. Subscription payment transaction is working. Now I want to cancel auto renewal after one payment. I have used this code in my functions.php. I have added the 
my feed name `$feed_names = array( 'Stripe Feed 1' );` and set the count `if ( $count == 1 ) {` but its not working. I cant understand how to solve this? I have not used any other code of gravity form in functions.php.

[LINK](https://docs.gravityforms.com/cancel-a-stripe-subscription-after-n-payments/)

```
 add_action( 'gform_post_add_subscription_payment', function ( $entry ) {
    if ( rgar( $entry, 'payment_status' ) == 'Active' ) {
        $feed       = gf_stripe()->get_payment_feed( $entry );
        $feed_name  = rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' );
        $feed_names = array( 'Stripe Feed 1' ); // update this line

        if ( in_array( $feed_name, $feed_names ) ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_addon_payment_transaction WHERE lead_id=%d", $entry['id'] ) );

            if ( $count == 1 ) { // update this line
                $result = gf_stripe()->cancel( $entry, $feed );
                gf_stripe()->log_debug( "gform_post_add_subscription_payment: Cancelling subscription (feed #{$feed['id']} - {$feed_name}) for entry #{$entry['id']}. Result: " . print_r( $result, 1 ) );
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

[Stripe Feeds Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgT1g.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is OK but I don't know where is your issue. I have a suggestion which is you can check the table `{$wpdb->prefix}gf_addon_payment_transaction` has been added data successfully while **Subscription** going on if your data has been added successfully then this add-on hook will work otherwise not because the table is empty.

**How you check the data?**

It's very easy you can just open up your database's table & check data exists or not.
You can check your Stripe add-on log for seeing what's going on.

Could try the following third-party [add-on](https://wordpress.org/plugins/installments-for-stripe-gf/)

You can check these necessary links

**[Creating a Stripe Feed](https://docs.gravityforms.com/setting-up-the-stripe-feeds/)**

**[logging-and-debugging](https://docs.gravityforms.com/logging-and-debugging/)**

**[theme/plugin conflict test](https://docs.gravityforms.com/testing-for-a-themeplugin-conflict/)**

**Note:**

> When testing you'll need to wait a day before cancelling the subscription to give Stripe time to capture the subscription payment and send the webhook.

I think will help.